# SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

Im creting a angular app that gets some data from a api available online, first i get the api information from my php script than in my angularjs app i go get the json result, but is giving me the error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON ", cant figure out why.

My php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// jSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = "http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/OPO";

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );
// Configuring curl options

// Getting results
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

echo json_encode($result);
```

Controller:

```
 $http.get('iata.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.originLatLong = response.data;
console.log($scope.originLatLong);
    });
```

Comment: What is `response` ?

Comment: 304 Not Modified

Comment: Did you try to parse the responce ?

Comment: try $scope.originLatLong = response;

Comment: this type of error generated when you try to parse or encode json.. I suspect there's some issue while encoding.

Comment: May you also include a snippet of the return JSON?

Comment: Try this console.log(JSON.parse(response.content));

Answer (score 0):

Just paste your URL in browser, it will return:

```
{"latitude":"41.2481002808","longitude":"-8.68138980865","code":"OPO"}true
```

You getting error, because you took all data from responce, with boolean parameter after JSON. 
So, check `responce` var first and then retrieve valid data you need.

Best regards.

Comment: Hello Viktor, i already tried is giving me a error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 70
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Comment: Your responce is not valid JSON, thats why you got this error. First of all check response variable and then retrieve correct child parameter.

Comment: I think the response has been updated, as I cannot see `}true` anymore

Comment: Thants strange, i still see true, i already console.log the response to see the childs, but it gives me this error when i console.log the response

Comment: If response has been updated, please, provide your JSON response.

Comment: I got the correct response by URL ```http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/OPO``` using Postman. So I'm pretty sure, your ```true``` comes from your ```iata.php``` file.